# Ошибка 'error_code': 15, 'error_msg': 'Access denied: no access to call this method'

Tags: vkontakte-api, api

При выполнении запроса: `https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post`

Выводит ошибку: `'error_code': 15, 'error_msg': 'Access denied: no access to call this method'`

При этом я получал токен с права администрации сообщества, но почему-то, он мне все равно не дает выложить пост в сообществе. (На своей странице я без проблем могу выложить пост)

Получал токен по этому адресу: `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ID_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,stories,photos,app_widget,groups,docs,manage&response_type=token&v=5.122`

Выполняю запрос с помощью python:

```
import requests
import json

a = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', data={
                                                              'owner_id': '-938344',
                                                              "access_token":"token",
                                                              'from_group': 1,
                                                              'message': 'Tets, test, test, tes',
                                                              'grant_type': 'password',
                                                              'v': 5.122,
                                                              'client_id': 'ID_приложения',
                                                              'client_secret': 'Защищённый ключ',
                                                              'username': 'login',
                                                              'password': 'password'}).json()
print(a)
```

В чем проблема подскажите, возможно, что-то делаю не так. Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен токен с доступом к стене. Для этого получайте его с указанием в `scope` параметра `wall`:

`https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ID_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,stories,photos,app_widget,groups,docs,manage,wall&response_type=token&v=5.122`